# Why Puppeteer not working in Brave™ portable?

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp, brave, brave-browser

All versions Works fine But , in the **Brave™ portable** from [portapps](https://github.com/portapps/portapps) (Edited Version) ,not working i use puppeteerSharp with Plugin Extrasharp, so when i try to open the browser , the browser open but without navigation , this is the output of browser logs :

```
D:/a/brave-portable/brave-portable/main.go:109 > Cannot import registry key error="reg file C:\\portapps\\brave-portable\\reg\\Brave-Browser-Development.reg not found" Fri, 20 May 2022 14:10:52 CEST INF ..\..\..\runneradmin\go\pkg\mod\github.com\portapps\portapps\v3@v3.4.0\portapps.go:168 > Process: C:\portapps\brave-portable\app\brave.exe Fri, 20 May 2022 14:10:52 CEST INF ..\..\..\runneradmin\go\pkg\mod\github.com\portapps\portapps\v3@v3.4.0\portapps.go:169 > Args (config file): Fri, 20 May 2022 14:10:52 CEST INF ..\..\..\runneradmin\go\pkg\mod\github.com\portapps\portapps\v3@v3.4.0\portapps.go:170 > Args (cmd line): --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-features=TranslateUI --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-sync --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain about:blank --disable-notifications --disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled --remote-debugging-port=0 --user-data-dir=C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\ov5gvgs3.hsi Fri, 20 May 2022 14:10:52 CEST INF ..\..\..\runneradmin\go\pkg\mod\github.com\portapps\portapps\v3@v3.4.0\portapps.go:171 > Args (hardcoded): --user-data-dir=C:\portapps\brave-portable\data --disable-brave-update --no-default-browser-check --disable-logging --disable-breakpad --disable-machine-id --disable-encryption-win Fri, 20 May 2022 14:10:52 CEST INF ..\..\..\runneradmin\go\pkg\mod\github.com\portapps\portapps\v3@v3.4.0\portapps.go:172 > Working dir: C:\portapps\brave-portable\app Fri, 20 May 2022 14:10:52 CEST INF ..\..\..\runneradmin\go\pkg\mod\github.com\portapps\portapps\v3@v3.4.0\portapps.go:173 > App path: C:\portapps\brave-portable\app Fri, 20 May 2022 14:10:52 CEST INF ..\..\..\runneradmin\go\pkg\mod\github.com\portapps\portapps\v3@v3.4.0\portapps.go:174 > Data path: C:\portapps\brave-portable\data Fri, 20 May 2022 14:10:52 CEST INF ..\..\..\runneradmin\go\pkg\mod\github.com\portapps\portapps\v3@v3.4.0\portapps.go:175 > Previous path: C:\portapps\brave-portable Fri, 20 May 2022 14:10:52 CEST INF ..\..\..\runneradmin\go\pkg\mod\github.com\portapps\portapps\v3@v3.4.0\portapps.go:181 > Launching Brave Fri, 20 May 2022 14:10:52 CEST INF ..\..\..\runneradmin\go\pkg\mod\github.com\portapps\portapps\v3@v3.4.0\portapps.go:191 > Exec C:\portapps\brave-portable\app\brave.exe --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-features=TranslateUI --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-sync --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain about:blank --disable-notifications --disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled --remote-debugging-port=0 --user-data-dir=C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\ov5gvgs3.hsi --user-data-dir=C:\portapps\brave-portable\data --disable-brave-update --no-default-browser-check --disable-logging --disable-breakpad --disable-machine-id --disable-encryption-win
```

**More details :**

*Platform*: **OB2** (Openbullet 2)

OS : **Windows 10**

Tested On : **97.XX and 101.XX**

App Log : **PuppeteerSharp.ProcessException: Timed out after 30000 ms while trying to connect to Base!**

N.B : Work Fine On **Selenium**

Answer (score 0):

*"TimeoutError: Timed out after 30000 ms while trying to connect to the browser! Only Chrome at revision r1056772 is guaranteed to work."* might be an explanation, as of 12/2022. Tried on Chrome Portable and got this error, very similar to yours.